# Sharepoint Online Search Results Sort by String with Text and Numbers Failing

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, display-template

In Sharepoint Online Search Center, I am having trouble sorting the Search Results using a Managed Property Text Field, as shown here:

[image]

I have set the Sorting options in the Search Results Web Part using a WordCustomRefiner (which allows sorting, while the original TcID Managed Property does not).

How do I modify the sorting parameters such that the search results are in alpha order for the first three characters, then numerical thereafter?

NOTE: Some of the libraries containing these items are over 5000 items which prohibits adding columns or altering the indexing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved:** I discovered that half of these records had inconsistent data in key sorting fields... once corrected, the items sorted properly.

**Lesson learned:** Turn every rock before throwing up your hands and posting to StackExchange...

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 calculated column, first column will contain first 3 characters and second column will contain numbers, then create 2 managed fields and use them in sorting.

Comment: Good answer, @Shafaqat, but I am already usung all of the 5 allowed slots for sorting in the Query Editor... and can't add columns on the libraries larger than 5000 items...

Comment: create a new list, firs create columns and then move data across, every slot in query editor appends the query, so if you have used all slots, just go to query text and manually append more sorting columns. I hope you already know all sorting columns should map to a managed sortable field.